# $\delta$ Notation in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

In this equation below, what is $\delta_{l,q}$ denoting? Is $\delta$ a standard notation, or anything to do with all one's or the basis matrix etc?

$$A_{ij}=\delta_{l,q}\left(\sum_{h=1}^n B_{l,h} + B_{l,q}\right)$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the [Kronecker delta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta).